# How to use multiple foreign keys in JPA?

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys

I'm starting a project to know more in detail JPA.

Context:
At the end of his internship, the student has a report to make and a presentation in front of his professor to do about the internship.

I've a database, which is called "grade_management". It must contains a "student", "presentation", "report", "professor" and a "mark" (there are several rating criteria such as expression, quality of powerpoint ...) table. But now it's empty, since I want to make it throught JPA.

I've a "Presentation" class. Which countain this:

```
@Entity
public class Presentation implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int presentation_id;
private Date date;
private mark_id;
private int professor_id;

public Soutenance() {}

public Soutenance(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

But the Presentation table contain 2 foreign key: professor_id and mark_id. 
My question is: ***How can I indicate that both of them are foreign key ?***

I'm sorry if I'm not clear, don't hesitation to ask question.

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reference other entities by their ID, but by a direct reference to the entity.

Something like that :

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "mark_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Mark mark; // supposed here that mark_id if link to entity `Mark`

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "professor_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // suppose "id" is the column name of the PK inside the table Professor.
private Professor professor; // supposed here that professor_id if link to entity `Professor`
```

This code is supposing that you use an unidirectional relation. 
For bidirectional you have to define this in the other side (Mark/Professor type)

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "professor")
private Presentation presentation;
```

Comment: In my case, a unidirectional relation is fine right ? Since the foreign key is only inside the presentation table ?

Comment: uni or bidirectional is not about where is the foreign key... it just about your needs... do you need the capability to traverse the relation in both side ? If not...so yes you can stay with an unidirectional relationship.

Comment: For the professor perspective, in 1 presentation, there is at least 1 but it can have n professor, so I guess its a `@ManyToOne`. Still, its an unidirectional relationship. So, after I added those table in a java class, it should create automatically my table with the fk. I'm going to try, thanks !!!!

Comment: Yes. Just think about one thing (as not define explicitly in your question) it could be either `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` depending of relation (one professor to many presentation or one prof to just one presentation) . You should take care of that

Comment: Its one professor to many pressentation. So I need to add nothing inside the Professor class ?

Comment: Its working !!! Thanks !! My database is created and the fk are in ! Thanks !

Comment: One last thing: What are the facade pattern for the EJB session bean ?

Comment: You should ask new question on SO for this subject.

Comment: ok, thanks ! Since I'm french and not that good in english, its a bit difficult ahah

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation, it looks like you have a Database named `grade_management` and in that database you have `"student", "presentation", "report", "professor" and a "mark"` tables (i.e: which are `@Entity` by themselves defined in their separate respective classes )

I'm not sure whether you have defined them or not. If not then you have to define them first and then use the refactored code mentioned below.

So, you  will have many-to-one relation mapping. You can annotate your foreign keys belonging to different tables using `@ManyToOne` annotation to indicate relation type and `@JoinColumn` annotation to indicate that this entity has a foreign key to the referenced table.

You can redefine your Presentation class show below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Presentation")
public class Presentation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="presentation_id")
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int presentation_id;
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mark_id")   
    private Mark mark_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "professor_id")  
    private Professor professor_id;

    public Soutenance() {}

    public Soutenance(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    //getter and setter 
}
```

Also, if you need more information to read upon for yourself you can always checkout this [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single) that explains everything you'll need to know.

Comment: So, if I understand well, the "@ManyToOne" is the cardinality, and the "@JoinColumn" is here to reference this professor_id to the professor_id in the professor table, right ? Didn't I need to write something in the professor and mark class ?

Comment: Exactly!! Yes, you will need separate `@Entity` class for each tables in the database. You don't need to manage any cardinality if your usecase is uni-directional. just define those entity classes as you would normally do and map foreign keys to your `Presentation` class.

Comment: Ok, I'm writing it, I'm going to test soon ! Thanks !

Comment: Done. I've open a new question about the ejb... if you can check it'll be cool ! ahah

Comment: Thanks!! I'll gladly check it out.

Comment: Did you checked ? :)

Comment: I did check it. Unfortunately, I don't know much about  Facade Pattern! :(